# При запуске приложения Android оно вылетает

Tags: java, android

Когда я компилирую и запускаю приложение на достаточно мощном смартфоне, то всё работает прекрасно, но как только я пробую запустить его на эмуляторе или на старом смартфоне, то оно просто вылетает, так и не запустившись. Ошибка в логах:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(850888900bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:788)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Я понял, что проблема в том, что приложение не запускается из-за попытки нарисовать слишком большое изображение. Но что за изображение? В приложении их полно. Как найти это изображение и уменьшить его?

BitmapDrawable:

```
final boolean clearColorFilter;
        if (mBlendModeFilter != null && paint.getColorFilter() == null) {
            paint.setColorFilter(mBlendModeFilter);
            clearColorFilter = true;
        } else {
            clearColorFilter = false;
        }
```

ImageView:

```
public void drawableHotspotChanged(float x, float y) {
        super.drawableHotspotChanged(x, y);

        if (mDrawable != null) {
            mDrawable.setHotspot(x, y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: а код какой-то можете показать?) ошибка это конечно тоже хорошо но код который к ней приводит не помешает. Так же желательно указать конфиги устройств на которых запускали

Comment: @Andrew Я не совсем понимаю, код чего. Показал что-то в правках. Запускаю на Samsung S20, в эмуляторе стоит Pixel XL, также не работает на asus zenfone 3 max

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка если прям ее брать:

```
Canvas: trying to draw too large(850888900bytes) bitmap
```

Переводим все на человеческий язык: `Приложение упало при попытке отрисовать очень большую картинку (850888900 байт)`. Если я ничего не путаю то ваша картинка как-бы довольно тяжелая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак у вас картинка на 1гб почти, а это много, очень много если быть точным. Вы это пытаетесь показать в ImageView судя по логу. Причина проблемы ( как мне кажется):

*Запуская приложение и пытаясь отобразить гиговую картинку, вы загружаете ОЗУ устройства, ОС как довольно жизнелюбивый алгоритм принимает решение грохнуть приложение но не помереть самой. В итоге происходит краш.*

Насколько я знаю Samsung S20 довольно свежее устройство с неплохим объемом ОЗУ (8 гб) которое потянет вашу картинку. Конечно можно юзать приложение только на крутых и мощных устройствах но это будет немного странно по меньшей мере. Вам нужно пересмотреть алгоритмы которые приводят к данной ошибке и провести их оптимизацию. В вашем случае приложение падает на этих строках (могу ошибаться):

```
DisplayListCanvas.java:229
RecordingCanvas.java:97
```

В ваших кусках кода я не понял какой это класс и что за строки. Но по простому если сказать - ваши устройства не тянут ту графику которую вы пытаетесь реализовать. Вот есть подобные вопросы, может помогут с решением: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111248/canvas-trying-to-draw-too-large-bitmap-when-android-n-display-size-set-larger), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642885/java-lang-runtimeexception-canvas-trying-to-draw-too-large-bitmap), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap) и [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099185/android-canvas-trying-to-draw-too-large). Так же советую посмотреть в сторону уменьшения размера картинки. Я не знаю что это за картинка ( я не супер силен в графике) но могу допустить что у нее будет просто супер разрешение. Попробуйте "ухудшить" разрешение картинки.